# CMake target version increment

Tags: cmake

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(LIB_VERSION_STRING ${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH})
...
set_target_properties(${PROGRAM_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION ${LIB_VERSION_STRING})
```

Is it possible to auto increment CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH each time target is rebuilt(not CMake is changed)?
Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The part code that you provided is runs at CMake time (probably its from CMakeLists.txt). There is no possible was for you to process the incremented value in Cmake time but what you can do is to run some cmake script in build time and pass the incremented value to your source code in a different way (for example by a header).

To run cmake script before compiling (goes into your CMakeLists.txt):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET your_project
    PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -P "your_cmake_script.cmake"
)
```

You need to put the code you want to run at compile time into a different file and tell CMake that you want to process that file before compiling...

your_cmake_script.cmake example:

```
#basic definitions
set(HEADER_FILE "increment.h")
set(CACHE_FILE "BuildNumberCache.txt")

#Reading data from file + incrementation
IF(EXISTS ${CACHE_FILE})
    file(READ ${CACHE_FILE} INCREMENTED_VALUE)
    math(EXPR INCREMENTED_VALUE "${INCREMENTED_VALUE}+1")
ELSE()
    set(INCREMENTED_VALUE "1")
ENDIF()

#Update the cache
file(WRITE ${CACHE_FILE} "${INCREMENTED_VALUE}")

#Create the header
file(WRITE ${HEADER_FILE} "#ifndef INCREMENT_H\n#define INCREMENT_H\n\n#define INCREMENTED_VALUE ${INCREMENTED_VALUE}\n\n#endif")
```

Don't forget to add increment.h to your project!

If you are looking for a more detailed example check this [github repo](https://github.com/nandee95/Auto_Build_Number_Increment).

Comment: this is nice. However, if you trigger a new build, then since #include "build_number.hpp" has changed, this is rebuilt and incremented, altough your real code didn't change. Can it be avoided ?

Comment: @Napseis Try excluding _increment.h_ from your `add_executable` call and add the directory that contains _increment.h_ using `target_include_directories`.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a *nice* way of doing this. There is a small demo of it here:
https://github.com/erichschroeter/cmake-auto-increment-build-number

... But in my opinion it's not worth the faff.